# Translate badblocks result from 1024 block size to 4096 block size?

Tags: kubuntu, ext4, badblocks

I have a 4TB hard drive which I ran the `badblocks` utility without passing in the `-b block-size` parameter. So I'm pretty sure it defaulted it to **1024**, and my 4TB drive/filesystem is most likely setup with a block size of **4096**. Is there a way I can translate the results to match the 4096 block size? For example, if the bad block is **#5** with `block-size=1024`, it would map to block **#2** with `block-size=4096`. Is that a valid conversion from 1024 to 4096?

If so, then I can re-run badblocks and specify a start and end range which will save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the default block size for `badblocks` is 1024. From [the documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/badblocks.8.html):

```
-b block_size
   Specify the size of blocks in bytes. The default is 1024.
```

Your math is also correct. If you are using Ext4 with a default configuration, then your partitions are using 4KB blocks. So, if the 777th block had an error found, you can round down:

```
Floor((777 * 1024) / 4096) = 192

∴ Block 192
```

For the sake of completeness, you can probably round down further to 190 when specifying a range:

```
sudo badblocks -sb 4096 /dev/sdb1 200 190
```